# Gantttitle on more than one line

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to draw a Gantt chart. However, I need 15 weeks to be represented and it wouldn't fit in a single page so I would like to divide it by 3 with each section representing 5 weeks.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfgantt}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    
    \begin{figure}[tbp]
    \begin{center}
    
    
    
    
    \begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
    y unit chart=0.5cm,
    vgrid,hgrid, 
    title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
    title left shift=.05,
    title right shift=-.05,
    title height=1,
    bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
    incomplete/.style={fill=white},
    progress label text={},
    bar height=0.7,
    group right shift=0,
    group top shift=.6,
    group height=.3]{1}{25}
    \gantttitle{Period}{25} \\
    
    \gantttitle{Week 1}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 2}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 3}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 4}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 5}{5} \\
    
    \ganttbar{first task}{1}{2} \\
    
    \gantttitle{Week 6}{5}
    \gantttitle{Week 7}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 8}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 9}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 10}{5} \\
    
    \ganttbar{second task}{1}{2} \\
    
    \gantttitle{Week 11}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 12}{5}
    \gantttitle{Week 13}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 14}{5} 
    \gantttitle{Week 15}{5} \\
    
    \ganttbar{third task}{1}{2} \\
    
    \end{ganttchart}
    
    \end{center}
    \caption{Gantt Chart}
    \end{figure}
    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

The result isn't what I expected.

[image]

I wanted the figure to display:

- Week 1
- First task
- Empty line
- Week 6
- Second task
- Empty line
- Week 11
- Third task
- Empty line

The empty lines would be used to add more tasks. The layout would look like this:

[image]

Another solution would be to display the entire period in one line in landscape mode but I couldn't achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure I am understanding the complete issue, but one thing I note is that `y unit title` and `y unit chart` must both share the same value, in this case I chose `.6cm`.

Also, the `bar height` can be set low (even negative!), However, here, I set it to `.7`.

The parameter `title height` is also an interesting parameter to play with.  Unfortunately, I could not tame it.

EDITED based on OP clarification.  The key seems to be knowing when to add extra `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\begin{center}

\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=.6cm,
y unit chart=.6cm,
vgrid,hgrid, 
title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
title left shift=.05,
title right shift=-.05,
title height=1,
bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
incomplete/.style={fill=white},
progress label text={},
bar height=.7,
group right shift=0,
group top shift=.6,
group height=.3]{1}{25}
\gantttitle{Period}{25} \\

\gantttitle{Week 1}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 2}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 3}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 4}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 5}{5} \\

\ganttbar{first task}{1}{2} \\

\\

\gantttitle{Week 6}{5}
\gantttitle{Week 7}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 8}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 9}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 10}{5} \\

\ganttbar{second task}{2}{6} \\

\ganttbar{third task}{5}{15} \\

\\

\gantttitle{Week 11}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 12}{5}
\gantttitle{Week 13}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 14}{5} 
\gantttitle{Week 15}{5} \\

\ganttbar{fourth task}{14}{25} \\


\end{ganttchart}

\end{center}
\caption{Gantt Chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot to be more clear. Why should they share the same value?

Comment: @Dunno because without it, the vertical period of the grey bars become unsynchronized with the week labels.  I can make the `y unit title` 2x as big as the `y unit chart` and that produces two rows of dotted boxes; however, the grey bars do not shift in accordance with the added row.

Comment: @Dunno Please see my edit.