# How to set height of a time slot in pgfgantt?

Tags: pgfgantt, height

Having a Gantt chart that a fragment of is attached below I want to reduce the spacing in all slots. Naming of chart elements according to the attached picture.

I already know I can set height of an element with for example `y unit chart=10mm` or, for specific elements, `bar height=0.2`.

What I want to achieve is to set the height of entire slot without affecting height of an element inside. In other words I want to reduce the spacing (blue dashed rectangles in the attached figure) without modifying an element.

The documentation available at: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf does not seem to cover such adjustment.

[image]

Comment: There are several questions on this site regarding adjusting the appearance of pgfgantt output, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611092/gantttitle-on-more-than-one-line, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617619/how-to-increase-the-space-between-groups-and-tasks-of-gantt-chart-pgfgantt-pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the answer is to combine both `y unit chart` and size of individual elements like `bar height=0.2`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
        vgrid,
        x unit=20mm,
        y unit chart=8mm,
        hgrid,
        bar top shift = .1,
        bar height=.9,
        group left shift=0,
        group right shift=0,
        group peaks width=.1
        ]{1}{3}
        \gantttitle{Time}{3} \\
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,3}{1} \\
        \ganttgroup{Object B}{1}{2} \\
        \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=green},inline]{task 1}{1}{1}\\
        \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=yellow},inline]{task 2}{2}{2}\\
        \ganttgroup{Object B}{1}{2} \\
        \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=green},inline]{task 1}{1}{1}\\
        \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=yellow},inline]{task 2}{2}{2}
        \ganttnewline[thick, red]
        \ganttbar{Object X}{1}{1} 
        \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=green},inline]{task 1}{1}{1}\\
        \ganttbar{Object Y}{1}{1} 
        \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=yellow},inline]{task 2}{2}{2}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

It seems like `bar height` adjust bars' height relatively to the slot's height.
It is required though to move them up a little with `bar top shift = .1` so they won't overlap with another slots.